# Can't select button with xpath in scrapy Python

Tags: css, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to crawl quotes from the website http://www.quotationspage.com/subjects/character/ my spider code is something like :

class quote(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'  # defining Name
    start_urls = ['http://www.quotationspage.com/subjects/character/']  # Targeted urls

```
def parse(self, response):
    total_count = len(response.xpath('//dl/dt').getall())  # counter for loop        
    for i in range(1, total_count + 1):  # loop for retriving data continuosly

        xp_quote = f'//dl/dt[{i}]/a/text()'
        xp_writer = f'//dl/dd[{i}]/b/a/text()'
        page_quote_writer = response.xpath(xp_writer).get()
        page_quote = response.xpath(xp_quote).get()

        yield {  # dictionay return
            'Writer': (page_quote_writer if page_quote_writer != None else 'Unable to fetch'),
            'Quote': (page_quote if page_quote != None else 'Unable to fetch')
        }

    next_page = response.css('#content tbody td a::attr(href)').getall()
    print(next_page)
```

So the problem is I'm unable to get anything in the next_page section, I have already checked with xpath as well but still same issue.
Now I know that the problem is with (this)      "response.css('#content tbody td a::attr(href)').getall() " ,   the css selector is not working, so I checked in chrome > Inspect element and copied the xpath and later css from there, but still no luck.
weird thing is this the same xpath or css sector is working fine in chrome > inspect elements > find section.

Help is already appreciated.

Comment: scapy != scrapy. watch your title

Comment: I think the button might be there in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
//td[@id='content']//tbody//td//a[b]/@href
```